# Security with Web Services in Java

Tags: java, web-services, security, jakarta-ee

We have a client that calls our web services. How can we make sure that it is only our client application that is calling the web service and not a client someone else created that calls our web services.

We'd like to avoid hard coding a password into the application.

Answer (score 3):

A quick answer to your question would be to look into OAuth.  Implementing OAuth correctly is a process so I would read up on the [protocol documentation](http://oauth.net/documentation/).  Here is a link to example OAuth [client libraries](http://oauth.net/code/).  I would also search StackOverflow for advice on OAuth implementations.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can use [two-legged OAuth](http://www.javacloud.net/post/3348887316/two-legged-oauth-in-java). This is a variation on standard OAuth and used by companies such as [SimpleGeo](http://developers.simplegeo.com/blog/2011/01/07/two-legged-oauth/). Then secure the communication with https and you have robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about clients not running in a browser, then you can use XSRF tokens, a secret per session that is either associated with some session key in your backend, or round-tripped through two separate paths, such as via a hidden form input and a cookie over a secure channel.  If you can't secure the channel, you have to make the tokens single-use.
See http://www.cgisecurity.com/csrf-faq.html#protectapp

You can't in the general case.  A reasonably intelligent hacker can probably reverse engineer any protocol you use, and extract any secrets you embed in the source code.

Comment: What do you mean by *"You can't in the general case"* ?  When you control the server side and have information on the server-side, you can, provably, design a fully secure system.  For example nobody, not a single person, managed to play Wow on *battle.net* (that is: on the real Blizzard servers, in the real economy, where all the legit players play), using faked credentials. Not a single cracking group managed to do it. It is mathematically not possible when done correctly. If you control the server side and if computation happens there, it's "Game Over [TM]" for the crackers.